# Flink: how to control the execution sequence of task

Tags: task, sequence, apache-flink

I am trying to write a Junit test which has two resources and operators, the first operator is used to persist the data into the state, then the second operator will retrieve state out.

I found the wired thing is the second operator is always run before the first one which persists the data into the state.

So, my question is how to control the execution sequence of the task within the same flink job program?

Comment: Can you clarify how your job is set up? I haven't really seen flink state used in this way? If you need to pass data between operators you can just send it directly, there isn't really a need to "persist data into the state".

Comment: My flink job has two consumer to listen on the differet kafka topic, one is used to update the hist data into the state, the other one is used to run some logic against the hist data. So, my testing is aiming to test this scenario, but not able to get the data persist into state firstly